# Absolute error, Relative error, Percentage error computation

Tags: numerical-methods, rounding-error, significant-figures

Round off the numbers $865250$ to four significant figures and compute Absolute Error, Relative Error, and Percentage error

My calculation is Absolute error-$50$, Relative error -$0.000057$, Percentage error - $0.0057%$.

But in my book, the answer is given an Absolute error - $50$, Relative error - $6.71 x 10^{-5}$, and Percentage Error - $6.71 x 10^{-3}$.

Could someone tell me what I am getting wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Rounding off $x = 865250$ to four significant figures results in $x' = 865200$.

The error is given by $x - x' = 865250 - 865200 = 50$.

**Absolute error**

$$e_a = |x - x'| = 50$$

**Relative error**

$$e_r = \dfrac{e_a}{x} = \dfrac{50}{865250} = 0.0000577868 \approx 5.77 \times 10^{-5}$$

**Percent error**

$$e_p = 100 e_r = 100(0.0000577868) = 0.005778676683039585 \approx 5.77 \times 10^{-3}$$

I think there is a typo in the book.